# How do I solve SonarCube issue: call is marked "javax.annotation.Nonnull" but null could be passed

Tags: java, sonarqube

I get SonarQube error from below code: param 1 and 2 in getProducts() call is marked as "javax.annotation.Nonnull" but null could be passed.

```
Summary summaryForOrg = null;
PoolSummary poolSummary = null;
summaryForOrg = getSummary(); //GET Api call
poolSummary = getPoolSummary(); //GET Api call

 // I get an error from SonarCube for parameter 1 and 2 below
products = SummaryUtils.getProducts(summaryForOrg, poolSummary);
```

Below is the signature of getProducts method:

public ProductsSummary getProducts(
@Nonnull Summary summary,
@Nonnull PoolSummary poolSummary,
) {
....
}

Comment: I'm not sure how Sonar exactly analyzes nulls propagation, but 1) it looks like it simply can see the null assignments to the variables (what if you merge the variables declarations and assignments discarding the `= null` in both cases?); 2) are the get-methods annotated with `@Nullable`?; 3) what does it do once you annotate the variables with `@Nonnull`?; 4) try to wrap the variables in `Objects.requireNonNull` (if possible, or better analyze the null check warning deeper); 5) suppress the warning (the last resort way, not recommending it).

Answer (score 0):

In your getProduct method, both the parameters are marked as nonNull and in your code you initialized both the parameters to null. There are chances for NullPointerException. Because of that you are getting this sonar issue.

Probable solution would be. You can initialize both the variables to empty string instead of null. It might resolve your issue.